# Process not terminating

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to run all mp3 files in the background by creating a process using the multiprocessing library.

```
import os
import subprocess
from multiprocessing import Process

def music_player():

    music_folder = "/home/pi/Music/"
    files = os.listdir(music_folder)
    for mp3_file in files:
        print("playing " + mp3_file)
        p = subprocess.Popen(["omxplayer","-o","local",music_folder+mp3_file],
                          stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                          stdin = subprocess.PIPE,
                          stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
        print(p)
        print(p.poll())
        print(p.pid)
        p.wait()



p = Process(target = music_player)
print(p, p.is_alive())
p.start()
print(p.pid)
print(p, p.is_alive())
command = raw_input()
if(command == "stop"):
    print("terminating...")
    p.terminate()
    print(p, p.is_alive())
    print(p.exitcode)
```

After entering the "stop" command the code exits but the music is still running and on executing `ps` I see 2 process of omxplayer which I then have to manually kill through `kill <pid>` to make the music stop.

I previously tried using the subprocess library and killing the process using `kill() and terminate()` but the same issue occurred.

Answer (score 0):

First observation, you don't need the ***multiprocessing*** module for what you're doing here.  ***subprocess*** is for creating and managing processes which will run other scripts and programs; ***multiprocessing*** is for creating and managing processes which will be calling code which is already internal to your (parent) script.

I suspect that your seeing the effect of buffering.  By the time you kill this process it's already buffered a significant amount of music out to the hardware (or even the OS buffers for the device).

What happens if you start the same program **omxplayer** from your shell, but in the background (as the ***&*** token to the end of your Unix shell command line to push a program into the background).  Then use the *kill* command on that process and see if you see the same results.

Comment: I run `omxplayer -o local <song name> &`  and I don't hear any audio. On running `ps` I see the omxplayer processes but `sudo kill <pid>` doesn't kill them they still appear in subsequent `ps` commands. 
How else do I go about playing the mp3 files in the background and continuing execution of my remaining python code (the above is just a test script I'm trying to get the music running in the background and being able to stop it with a command)

Comment: Looking at http://elinux.org/Omxplayer I see that this is a console player which is written with some sort of keyboard handling event loop.  Starting it from your shell, in the background probably causes it to be stopped via the SIGTTIN or SIGTTOUT signals ... background processes attempting to access their controlling terminal.  It may be that you need to run this application under https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/ (Python pexpect), so that the process has a pseudo-terminal to satisfy its own resource requirements (a terminal).